# SQL Server query returning no results in PHP, but runs fine in Management Studio

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a rather large query that works fine in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. However when I try to run the same query in PHP, I'm getting no results. Here is my code, I know this is the worst way to connect to the database.

```
Public function GetClockedHours() {
    $conn = odbc_connect('easydo', '', '');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }
    $sql = "WITH ByDays AS ( -- Number the entry register in each day
SELECT 
EventTm AS T,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EventTm,102) AS Day,
FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,EventTm)) DayNumber,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,EventTm)) ORDER BY EventTm) InDay 
FROM CHINA_VISION_DorEvents
Where DorCtrls_Ref = '16' AND CardCode = '000006f1' AND CONVERT(Date,EventTm) >  dateadd(day, -7, getdate())
)

,Diffs AS (
SELECT 
E.Day,
E.T ET, O.T OT, O.T-E.T Diff, 
DATEDIFF(S,E.T,O.T) DiffSeconds -- difference in seconds
 FROM 
(SELECT BE.T, BE.Day, BE.InDay 
 FROM ByDays BE 
 WHERE BE.InDay % 2 = 1) E -- Even rows
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT BO.T, BO.Day, BO.InDay 
 FROM ByDays BO 
 WHERE BO.InDay % 2 = 0) O -- Odd rows
ON E.InDay + 1 = O.InDay -- Join rows (1,2), (3,4) and so on
AND E.Day = O.Day --  in the same day
)


SELECT Day, 
SUM(DiffSeconds) Seconds, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 
(DATEADD(S, SUM(DiffSeconds), '1900-01-01T00:00:00')),
108) TotalHHMMSS -- The same, formatted as HH:MM:SS
FROM Diffs GROUP BY Day
ORDER BY Day desc";
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        exit("Error in SQL");
    }
    $array = array();
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs, $i)) {
        foreach ($row AS $key => $value) {
            $array[$i][$key] = $row[$key];
        }
        $i++;
    }
    var_dump($array);
    return $array;
}
```

The expected result would be an array of results and the results would be:

```
   Date    Seconds   hours
2015.01.27  18055   05:00:55
2015.01.26  33491   09:18:11
2015.01.23  32649   09:04:09
2015.01.22  31554   08:45:54
2015.01.21  31889   08:51:29
```

However what were are getting is an array of nothing.

Comment: You should fully quality your objects - databasename.schema.object

Comment: your foreach loop is pointless. why not just `while(...) { $array[] = $row; }`?

Comment: Have you tried printing $key and $value?

Why is it that you're expecting three data points in the output, but only assigning $key to your array?

Answer (score 0):

How many results sets do you get back? If it's more than 1 then you need to pick the correct resultset:

```
bool odbc_next_result ( resource $result_id )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-next-result.php

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. In my case I was executing like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$resultSet = odbc_exec($sqllink, $sql);

while ($data = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";
    $resultSet2 = odbc_exec($sqllink, $sql);//failed here
    while ($data2 = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet2)) {

           //something here

    }
}
```

and I changed like this and it worked

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$resultSet = odbc_exec($sqllink, $sql);

// Create an array and store the results

$queryResult = array();

while ($data = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet)) {

    // push the required content into the array

    $queryResult[$data['id']]['name'] = $data[name];
}

foreach($queryResult as $row) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";
    $resultSet2 = odbc_exec($sqllink, $sql);
    while ($data2 = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet2)) {

        // something here

    }
}
```